# Correct/Simplest form of: Adding an ion-icon button to the navbar in Ionic 2

Tags: html, ionic2

I am adding an ion-icon button to the ion-navbar in an Ionic 2 app.

It works correctly, but this solution seems rather verbose.

I would like to confirm that this is the correct/simplest-form/best-practice approach:

```html
<ion-navbar>
  <ion-title>Books</ion-title>

  <ion-buttons end>
    <button ion-button icon-only [navPush]="bookEditPage">
        <ion-icon name="add" color="navigation"></ion-icon>
      </button>
  </ion-buttons>
</ion-navbar>
```

Comment: where you able to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to confirm that this is the
>   correct/simplest-form/best-practice approach.

**It's perfect :)**

It may seems like a little verbose, but each part of the code has its purpose. The `<ion-buttons end>...</ion-buttons>` will act as a container, to place the button in the right place.

In this case you're using `end`, and as you can see in [this answer](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/nav-bar-with-button-on-left-side/51963/5):

> `start` and `end` follow the UI pattern for the platform
>
> So `<ion-buttons start>` would be on the left for ios and be the first
>   button on the right for android.
>
> `<ion-buttons end>` would be on the right for ios and the last button on
>   the right for android.
>
> `left`/`right` are provide as a way to over ride that.

Then inside of that container, you just need to place the button, in this case, with an icon inside:

```
<button ion-button icon-only [navPush]="bookEditPage">
  <ion-icon name="add" color="navigation"></ion-icon>
</button>
```